# How can I create Instagram's changing gradient background in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I create Instagram like auto changing gradient background color in flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know exactly what you mean by "Instagram-like auto changing gradient" but I am guessing you mean a smooth color transition in a container. For that, there are two main approaches.

- The simplest one: use an [Animated Container](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/animated-container) and assign its color property to a local variable that you can change later on using `setState()`. `AnimatedContainer` will interpolate the values between the initial and the final color in the states, creating the effect.
- Use an [Animated Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html) to create a `Tween` that interpolates colors and control when and how it should change with an `AnimationController`. [In this Medium article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-animation-i-background-color-transition-39dcbada7335) you can find more information on this approach.

Comment: This medium link helped me

Comment: I have written simple blog for the same: https://betterprogramming.pub/instagram-gradient-animation-for-flutter-1d74d3869997

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know exactly what you mean by "Instagram-like auto changing gradient":
but I'm assuming you to reach the same look that instagram gradient has:
[such as this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9gSB.png)

it can be done like this:

```
 Container(
    margin:
        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(10)),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(getProportionateScreenWidth(12)),
    height: getProportionateScreenHeight(44),
    width: getProportionateScreenWidth(44),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topRight,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        colors: [
          Colors.purple,
          Colors.pink,
         Colors.orange,
        ],
      ),
      // color: color,
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
    child: SvgPicture.asset(icon!,color: Colors.white,),
  ),
```